# Simple Regex c#, Replace and Split Question

Tags: c#, regex, replace, split

I am trying to remove " from a string using Regex.

I am receiving a string into a method, I would like to take the string and split it up into the words that are in the string.

My Code is below, hopefully you can see what I am doing.

The problem I am having is trying to tell Regex that " is what I would like to remove. I have tried numerous ways: I have searched Google for a answer and have had to resort to here.

`search_string` looks like this:  `blah="blah" la="la" ta="ta"` and in the end I want just the `blah blah la la ta ta`.

```
public blahblah blahblah(blah blah, string search_string)
        {                
            Regex r = new Regex(@"/"+");

            string s3 = r.Replace(search_string, @" ");

            Regex r2 = new Regex(" ");
            Regex r3 = new Regex("=");

            string[] new_Split = { };

            string[] split_String = r2.Split(s3);


            foreach (string match in split_String)
            {
                new_Split = r3.Split(match);

            }

            //do blahblah stuff with new_Split[1] .. etc
            // new_Split[0] should be blah and new_Split[1] should 
            //     be blah with out "", not "blah"


            return blah_Found;
```

Comment: dont worry so much about the return or the class or paramaters etc, its mainly the bloody regex i cant work out i have tried @"\"+"  and  "\"+"  and @"//"+"  and @""+", most are not allowed due to synax in c# but god dam regex is really giving me a hard time.

Comment: I really doubt you need regex for this. Just so I'm clear `blah="blah" la="la" ta="ta"` should become `blah blah la la ta ta`

Comment: what are `blah` and `blahblah`? The line `Regex r = new Regex(@"/"+");` doesen't compile. When is `blah_Found` declared?

Comment: Could you edit the question to show what string you have, and what string you would like, we can make the regex and, even supply the code. I'm reading you want `blah="blah" la="la" ta="ta"` to become `blah blah la la ta ta`, essentialy removing `"` and `=`, right?

Comment: @ Ash ya

@ Jodrell, i left some stuff out sorry, it compiles for me, was more of a genral question sorry.

Comment: ya jordel, but the string is always changing, one time i may pass something="something" the other i may pass something="something" some="some" blah="something", it seems like Ibrams technique is the one i am after.

Comment: Does the question actually regard splitting the string into name value pairs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
myString = myString.Replace( "\"", String.Empty );
```

---

[Update]

The String.Empty or "" is not a space char. You wrote this

```
blah="blah" la="la" ta="ta"
```

you want to convert to

```
blah blah la la ta ta
```

So you have white spaces anyway. If you want this:

```
blahblahlalatata
```

you need to remove them too:

```
myString = myString.Replace( "\"", String.Empty ).Replace( " ", String.Empty );
```

for '=' do it again, and so on...

You need to be more precise in your questions.

Comment: i didnt even need regex lol, I tried this method and i think it is the way i will go, problem is it seems to leave a space where the " use to be i tried changing String.Empty to "" and it still left a space.

Comment: ya it seems to leave a space :( but considering the string will change everytime (but the same rough format) this may be the only option.

Comment: @Scott, this leaves the `=` intact, your question asks to remove them, no?

Comment: @ Jodrell well to a degree , i can figure out how to remove the = my main issue was with the " breaking syntax even with exscape char.

when i use the above code it seems i get a space char where " use to be, i would like " removed but no space char, so it replaced with nothing not even a space char, if you know what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick thought - and barking maybe up entirely the wrong tree, but wouldnt you want something like

```
Regex r = new Regex("(\".*\")");
```

eg, a reg expression of ".*"

Comment: ya mate thats kinda what i am after a wild card delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it.
It will Search for anything in that form: SomeWord="somethingelse"
and replace it with SomeWord somethingelse

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(\w+)=\""(.+)\""");
var result = regex.Replace("bla=\"bla\"", "$1 $2");
```

Comment: that works thanks mate, unfortuantly i am passing up to muliple blahblahs... so one time i may pass blah="blah"  and the other i may pass blah="blah" meh="meh" etc="etc"... and so on :(

Comment: Ah, I saw the 2 regexes and thought you were first splitting and then cleaning them one by one...

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with Regex.
Anyway if you only need to remove = and " and split words you could try:

```
string[] arr = s
    .Replace("="," ")
    .Replace("\""," ")
    .Split(new string[1] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: interesting Marco trying that now, if i can avoid regex i would LOVE to!, just by reading that it should place the words into a array??

Trying code now , thanks.

Comment: code works mate but how would i adjust it to not replace with a space char " " but to replace with nothing? not even a space char?

Comment: @scott: use `""` :) But if you replace with an empty string I don't know if `Split` function works...

Answer (score 0):

I did it in 2 passes

```
string input = "blah=\"blah\" la=\"la\" ta=\"ta\"";

//replace " and = with a space
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "[\"=]", " ");
//condense the spaces
output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\s+", " ");
```

EDIT:
Treating `"` and `=` differently as per comment.

```
string input = "blah=\"blah\" la=\"la\" ta=\"ta\"";

//replace " and = with a space
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "\"", String.Empty);
output = Regex.Replace(output, "=", " ");
```

Clearly regex is a bit overkill here.

Comment: thanks mate that works, problem is i would like not a space to be where " use to be but nothing. so remove " not replace with a space char so to speak , if you know what i mean?